# changing facebook app credentials breaking omniauth-facebook

Tags: ruby, facebook, omniauth

I set local environment variables for facebook key / secret in a file to use with `omniauth-facebook` and everything works perfectly.

Thought it might be a good idea to have 2 facebook apps, one for dev, one for the live app. Unfortunately, when I swap out the keys in the `environment_variables.rb`, I get the following error on every auth attempt:

> OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook::Authorization Code Error at /auth/facebook/callback

All of the settings for the two apps are identical. I swapped back in the live app credentials, and it works again.

```
# only change to app is changing these values
ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'] = '*******************'
ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'] = '***********************************'
```

What I've tried:

- restarting server (of course)
- removing sandbox mode for dev app
- resetting secret key for dev app
- clearing all browsing data from browser
- manually deleting cookies

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was stupid as anything, but I forgot to change the appId in the javascript. Now I pass the appId in as meta content:

```
<!-- head partial -->
<meta name="facebook-app-id" content="<%= ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'] %>">
```

And then grab it with jquery

```
// facebook setup script
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId  : $('meta[name="facebook-app-id"]').attr('content'),
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });
};
```